# What is the purpose these long string reply-to email addresses?

Tags: email, html-email

For example Groupon and Facebook seem to use these.

Groupon `<reply-fec4e341ec32311-125727_HTML-677829183-96988-0@e.groupon.com>`

`Reply to Comment <g+41wq2z1j00000000u2kx002eqs1u620s0037hlmwm4621up33@groups.facebook.com>`

In the facebook example - it makes sense that I could be replying to a particular comment thread and this is a unique hash that lets me do so from within an e-mail.

As for the groupon example, I am not aware of the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say Groupon does it so they can tie replies/complaints to a specific campaign.  They must send out many millions of mails a day, and probably have many hundreds of campaigns running at the same time.  Being able to automatically link feedback to a campaign is probably a huge time saver, and provides useful KPI stats.